# Numerical triple integration of multivariate equations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, matlab

The form of my problem is as follows:

$\Psi=C\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(f(x,y)\times \left(\int_0^t g(x,t)dt\right)dxdy\right)$

I have already attempted numerical solutions using Matlab's `integrate3`, without success.

In any case I doubt `integrate3` is the right approach as that is meant for problems of the form:

$\Psi=\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f f(x,y,z)dxdydz$

Similarly, attempts made with scipy's integration toolkit have also not borne fruit.

I have attempted to first calculate $\int_0^tg(x,t)$ at discrete $x$ values and then place it in $\Psi$ but for rather obvious reasons that does not work either.

Additionally, $g(x,t)$ cannot be factored in the form of $h(x)\times i(t)$, which might have allowed for a by parts solution which might be integrated symbolically (for x) and numerically for t.

Also $\int_0^t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  g(x,t)$ has singularities at multiple points.

Is there a canonical method of solving this?

**UPDATE**

The equations being modeled are given in the paper by [Shen et. al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030101049287053C) (in spherical coordinates, hence the reduction of integrals) as:

$\Theta=\frac{\theta}{t_c}\int_0^t\frac{1}{1+\frac{2t^\prime}{t_c}}\left[1-\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{-2mg}{1+2\frac{t^\prime}{t_c}}\right)dt^\prime\right]$

and

$U_p=C\int_0^\infty \mathrm{exp}[-(1+\mathrm{i}V)g]\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i}\Theta) dg$

With the approximation $\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i}\Theta)\approx1-\mathrm{i}\Theta$

$U=C\int_0^{\infty}(1-\mathrm{i}\Theta)\mathrm{exp}[-(1+\mathrm{i}V)g]dg$

The form I've explained in the original question is obtained on converting to Cartesian coordinates.

**UPDATE 3**

Using symbolic math I get

```
for t=1:1000:Tmax
phi = (theta/tc)* int((1/(1+2*(tp/tc)))*[1-exp((2*m*g)/(1+(2*            
(tp/tc))))],tp,0,t);
phi=subs(phi)
preU=exp(-(1+1i*V)*g)*exp(-1i*phi);

Urun=int(preU,g,0,inf); % Evaluated at t=0

tt(t+1)=t+1;
end

Io= 3/193 - 84i/693;

Ir=abs(Io);

Uplot = (vpa(abs(Urun))./Ir).^2
```

However this returns a value of Uplot in the form `abs(numeric::int())` which cannot be plotted.

Additionally, attempting to numerically integrate the second portion of the integral (the portion returning the `abs(numeric::int())` form) I get an array of NaN's.

Needless to say, still no plot.

```
for t=1:1:Tmax
phi = (theta/tc)* int((1/(1+2*(tp/tc)))*[1-exp((2*m*g)/(1+(2*
(tp/tc))))],tp,0,t);
phi=subs(phi);
preU=exp(-(1+1i*V)*g)*(1-1i*phi);

UrunF=matlabFunction(preU)
UrunNum(t)=integral(UrunF,0,inf);

tt(t+1)=t+1;
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As written, your integral does not make any sense; there is probably a typo in it. In $\int_0^tg(x,t)dt$ the variable $t$ is used as a dummy variable of integration and in the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: No, actually i'm solving a variant of a paper by [Shen et. al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030101049287053C) and they seem to have used the same form.

Comment: I think you need to go very carefully through your post. None of the mathematics you have there makes any sense. Perhaps there are some typos?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't know if posting screen-shots of the equations in paper is allowed here but I checked three times, and the equations are copied verbatim..

Comment: Well, for one thing: Where is the $dt$ meant to be in the first equation of the update?

Comment: Also: What depends on what? $t$ and $g$ seem to be the integration variables. It looks like $\Theta$ is meant to depend on $t$ and $g$. What other things are constants vs functions?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the variable in $\Theta$, also $g$ and $t$ are the only variables involved, ie. $t_c$, $m$,$\theta$ and $V$ are known quantities.. @JohnBarber

Comment: I believe the form of $U$ given in your first update has an analytic solution, and therefore doesn't need to be integrated numerically.

Comment: The inner integral $\Theta$ does seem to have an analytic solution however it seems intractable once substituted into $U$.

Comment: Actually, to clarify, the model solved in the paper, has been analytically solved, however I am working on a programmatic approach to loosen some restrictions made during the analytical solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(f(x,y)\times \left(\int_0^t g(x,\tau)d\tau\right)dxdy\right), $ I would start by defining a subfunction that computes $G(x, t) \equiv \int_0^t g(x,\tau)d\tau, $ and then, for each $t,$ integrate $f(x,y)\times G(x, t)$ over the plane with `integral2`.

As an example with some arbitrary functions $f$ and $g:$

```
f = @(x, y) exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2));
g = @(t, x) abs(x) .* exp(-t);
t_values = 0:10;
n = numel (t_values);
S = nan (n, 1);
for i = 1:n
  t = t_values(i);  
  G = @(x) arrayfun(@(x) integral(@(tau) g(tau, x), 0, t), x);
  S(i) = integral2 (@(x, y) f(x, y) .* G(x), -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf);
end
plot (t_values, S)
```